# How to abort a partially-typed SQLite command without executing it?

Tags: sqlite

If I start typing a multi-line command on the SQLite shell, and change my mind mid-way, how do I get back to shell prompt again without causing SQLite to execute the current command?

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO
   ...> mytable VALUES
   ...> ^C                  <---- changed my mind here, but ^C doesn't work
   ...>;                    <---- had to type ; to end the command
Error: near ";": syntax error   <---- want to avoid this
```

As you can see above, SQLite tried to execute invalid command. Is there a way I can press a key combination and return to a clean prompt again?

Comment: Sending an `EOF` using `CTRL+D` seems like it should work, but doesn't. Sending an interrupt using `CTRL+C` aborts a multiline input in Postgresql's `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> which will erase from the cursor to the beginning of the line. To erase from the cursor to the end of the line, if needed: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but any way to totally clear the command buffer? Previous lines too!

Comment: @slowpoison: The keystrokes I listed are from the `readline` library which SQLite uses if it's available. Readline doesn't have a `clear-history` function as far as I know.